# Two queries to two lists?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

At the moment, I have this which works fine:

```
using (connection = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
{
    using (command = new SqlCommand(@"select * from tbl1", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int ColIndex1 = reader.GetOrdinal("col_1");
                int ColIndex2 = reader.GetOrdinal("col_2");

                Console.Write(reader.GetString(ColIndex1);
                Console.Write(" - ");
                Console.Write(reader.GetString(ColIndex2);
                Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have another query which I run separately, but that second query needs the first query, which means I end up running the first query twice.  To avoid that, if I changed the command line to:

```
using (command = new SqlCommand(@"select * from tbl1; select * from tbl2", connection))
```

How do I get each query into a separate list?  I understand how to get a single query into a list, i.e:

```
public class Data
{
    public int ColumnIndex1 { get; set; }
    public int ColumnIndex2 { get; set; }
}

List<Data> list = new List<Data>();

list.Add(new Data(ColIndex1, ColIndex2));
```

The first query is used to create directories on the hard drive.  The second query then uses the first query and then adds files to the created directories.

Comment: How are the two tables similar? Do they have exactly the same columns?

Comment: "but that second query needs the first query" - in what way, **exactly** ?

Comment: @MarcGravell, Added a paragraph at the end to explain the relationship between the 2 queries.

Comment: @adaam, both queries have different amounts of columns.  I have added a new paragraph at the end of the question explaining the relationship between the 2 queries.

Comment: btw, since columns don't change order between rows, you should move the `GetOrdinal` calls **outside** of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (connection = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
{
    using (command = new SqlCommand(@"select * from tbl1", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // read first grid
            }
            if(reader.NextResult())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // read second grid
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I strongly suggest using helper tools, for example, via "dapper":

```
List<FirstType> first;
List<FirstType> second;
using(var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, args))
{
    first = multi.Read<FirstType>().ToList();
    second = multi.Read<SecondType>().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to investigate the `NextResult` method on the `IDataReader` interface. This allows you to move through multiple result sets.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx